# Spring Boot redirect to another url

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, controller

In my spring boot project i wanted to do a redirection from http://localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8080/birdspotting. This is the code of the Home controller:

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage() {
        return "redirect:/birdspotting";
    }
}
```

The result of going to http://localhost:8080 is a print of redirect:/birdspotting

Comment: use `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `@RestController` = `@Controller` + `@RequestBody`

Which will send json response but we are expecting view resolver to return the page or redirect url.

So use `@Controller` instead of `@RestController` to fix the issue.

**Update**:

If you want to use both in Same controller then use `@Controller` on class level and then wherever you want to return API call response put `@ResponseBody` on method and wherever you want to return web browser page don't put `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: How could I do if I need to have both? I mean, an answer in case of API call and a redirection in case of a web browse?

Comment: Updated the answer...let me know for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the other endpoint like:

```java
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage() {
        return "redirect:/birdspotting";
    }

    @GetMapping("/birdspotting")
    public String birdspottingPage() {
        return "birdspotting";
    }
```

It's expect you have `birdspotting.html` in your templates.